# Discord.NET bot sharing the same DatabaseContext between all modules when using .AddDbContext() and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, discord.net

I'm creating a Discord Bot that is supposed to create and dispose a `DatabaseContext` when a command is issued by a guild member. The problem is that the same `DatabaseContext` is being shared between modules. I'm already using `.AddDbContext()` instead od `.AddDbContextPool()` so I don't understand this behaviour.

I'm using Discord.NET, EFCore and Dependency Injection.

This is my Program.cs file:

```cs
class Program
{
    private const string _token = "token";
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly CommandService _commands;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    private Program()
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _commands = new CommandService();
        _client.Log += Log;
        _commands.Log += Log;
        _services = ConfigureServices();
    }

    private IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
    {
        var map = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton(_client)
            .AddSingleton(_commands)
            .AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => 
                options.UseMySql(SharedConfiguration.connectionString,
                new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(5, 7))));

        return map.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.UtcNow} - {msg.Severity}] {msg.ToString()}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MainAsync()
    {
        await InitCommands();

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, _token);
        await _client.StartAsync();

        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private async Task InitCommands()
    {
        await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);

        _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
    }

    private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage messageParam)
    {
        var message = messageParam as SocketUserMessage;
        if (message == null) return;

        int argPos = 0;

        if (!(message.HasStringPrefix("b.", ref argPos) ||
            message.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos)) ||
            message.Author.IsBot)
            return;

        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

        await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);
    }
}
```

This is an example of a module:

```cs
public class UserModule : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly CommandService _commands;
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    private UserModule(DiscordSocketClient client, CommandService commands, DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _client = client;
        _commands = commands;
        _context = context;
    }

    [Command("user")]
    public async Task Stats(IUser dUser = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_context.ContextId);
    }
}
```

However, when I run `b.user` twice, the `ContextId` is the same.
This is causing critical caching issues in my app, because the database is shared between this discord bot and another app.

What can I do so that a `DatabaseContext` is created everytime a command is issued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your bot is a single instance, hence the injected services are only resolved a single time.

Instead of injecting the `DbContext` inject a `IServiceScopeFactory`, and create a seperate scope for each request:

```
public class UserModule : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly CommandService _commands;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    private UserModule(DiscordSocketClient client, CommandService commands, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _client = client;
        _commands = commands;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    [Command("user")]
    public async Task Stats(IUser dUser = null)
    {
        using(var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {   
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();           
            Console.WriteLine(dbContext.ContextId);
        }
    }
}
```